# Flutter webpage navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

How to get following result in flutter web app using Getx package

On tapping the container in intiating screen, I wish to pass parameters in following fashion ( 2 variable parameters and 1 fixed parameter i.e. product) which should open webpage with following url

**https://myapp.local/variableParameter1/variableParameter2/product**
Above link should be without # and also when user opens above link, should lead to (ProductScreen) with 2 parameters being passed as arguments

My code is structured in following fashion and works well on mobile devices.

**Part of intiating screen**

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
    //some content inside
  ),
  onTap: () {
      Get.toNamed(
          '/product/$variableParameter1/$variableParameter2',
      );
  },
)
```

**Part of main.dart file**

```
GetPage(
    name: '/productscreen/variableparameter1/variableparameter1',
    page: () => ProductScreen(),
    binding: ProductScreenBinding(),
),
```

**Part of controllers for ProductScreen**

```
class ProductController extends GetxController {
  var screenprm1 =Get.arguments[0].toString().obs;
  var screenprm2 =Get.arguments[1].toString().obs;
}
```

Comment: Get toNamed(nameOgPage, arguments:[variableParameter1, variableParameter2]);

Comment: Get toNamed(nameOfPage, arguments:[variableParameter1, variableParameter2]); and 
Get.toNamed('/product/$variableParameter1/$variableParameter2',); serves same purpose, question relates to webpage navigation